# GridBagLayout row span issue

Tags: java, gridbaglayout

I'm facing a strange problem with the GridBagLayout. I have reduced it to a simple example with 4 panels, 2 cols and 3 rows. Panels have a preferred size to make them square (1 and 4) or rectangular (2 and 3).

```
   Expected                  Real result
---------------            ---------------
|  1   |  3   |            |  1   |  3   |
|      |      |            |      |      |
|      |      |            |      |      |
|------|      |            |------|      |
|  2   |      |            : space|      |
|      |      |            |------|      |
|      |------|            |  2   |------|
|      |  4   |            |      | space:
|      |      |            |      |------|
|      |      |            |      |  4   |
---------------            |      |      |
                           |      |      |
                           ---------------
                           : extra space :
                           ...............
```

Adding panels in order as they are numbered gives a bad result (actually not the expected one), whereas changing the add order to 1-3-2-4 gives a good result.
Transposing it horizontally ends up with a similar result.
I can't figure out neither why add order is important, nor why rows overlap with an extra space between panels.

What is the missing point in my logic?
How can I achieve the expected result without "add order" considerations?

(I tried MigLayout and its cell placing feature: it falls in the same hole, and order doesn't change anything)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestLayout
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("test gridbag");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    Dimension rectDim = new Dimension(100, 200);
    Dimension carDim = new Dimension(100, 100);

    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    panel1.add(new JLabel("1"));
    panel1.setPreferredSize(carDim);
    GridBagConstraints c1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c1.gridx = 0;
    c1.gridy = 0;
    c1.gridheight = 1;
    contentPane.add(panel1, c1);

    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    panel2.add(new JLabel("2"));
    panel2.setPreferredSize(rectDim);
    GridBagConstraints c2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c2.gridx = 0;
    c2.gridy = 1;
    c2.gridheight = 2;
    contentPane.add(panel2, c2);

    JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
    panel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    panel3.add(new JLabel("3"));
    panel3.setPreferredSize(rectDim);
    GridBagConstraints c3 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c3.gridx = 1;
    c3.gridy = 0;
    c3.gridheight = 2;
    contentPane.add(panel3, c3);

    JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
    panel4.add(new JLabel("4"));
    panel4.setPreferredSize(carDim);
    GridBagConstraints c4 = new GridBagConstraints();
    c4.gridx = 1;
    c4.gridy = 2;
    c4.gridheight = 1;
    contentPane.add(panel4, c4);

    // TODO change add order to 1-3-2-4 for expected result

    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: just for the future - use 3rd party layout manager - MigLayout is my favorite